# 2 separate data sources for UITableView/UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a static tableview with 4 predefined cells in interface builder. The searchcontroller for the tableviewcontroller that contains this static tableview has an entirely different data source -- that is, the data that the user is searching is not in these 4 static cells.

Before, with the now-deprecated `UISearchDisplayController`, I could just do:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = _searchResultsController;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = _searchResultsController;
```

With `_searchResultsController` implementing the tableview data methods. I am now trying to add a `staticTableView` property to the searchresultscontroller, except it isn't getting passed and I'm unsure of how I should go about this.

OriginalTableViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _searchResultsController = [CustomSearchResultsController new];
    self.searchResultsController.originalTableViewController = self;
    self.searchResultsController.searchController = self.searchController;
    self.searchResultsController.staticTableView = self.tableView;
    self.tableView.dataSource = _searchResultsController;
    self.tableView.delegate = _searchResultsController;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

CustomSearchController.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    } else {
        return [self.staticTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        // do some stuff with the separate data source
        return cell;
    } else {
        return [self.staticTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        // do some stuff with the separate data srouce
    } else {
        [self.originalTableViewController tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

This currently crashes on `numberOfRowsInSection` with the count being 0. Even if I manually hard-code the `return 4;`, it will still crash and say that it failed to obtain a cell from it's data source.

Am I missing something? Is this the ideal way to go about doing this sort of thing? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to show the search results *and* the static cells, or search results *instead of* the static cells?

Comment: Show the search results when searching, then when the searchcontroller is inactive, show the static cells again.

Comment: If you create a UISearchController with a resultsController, the UISearchController will handle switching from the static tableViewController to the resultsController automatically - so the resultsController only needs to handle displaying the search results, not the static cells.

Comment: That was it pbasdf, please make this an answer and I will accept it. I'm embarrassed I missed such an obvious initializer!

Comment: Thanks.  As they say, it's only obvious if you know it.  I still get confused by the UISearchController terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a `UISearchController` with a `resultsController`, using the initialiser:

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
```

the `UISearchController` will handle switching from your static table view controller to the `resultsController` automatically - so the `resultsController` only needs to handle displaying the search results, not the static cells.